# Race Conditions in C

Tags: c, operating-system, race-condition

I'm having trouble analyzing a problem on a past OS exam. It is as follows:

Describe the output of the following program. Does a race condition exist?

```
int count=0;
int main(void)
{   
    pid_t pid;      
    if( (pid = fork()) < 0)     
    {       
        perror("Fork error");       
        exit(1);    
    }   
    else if( pid == 0)  
    {       
        charatatime("Output 1\n");  
    }       
    else    
    {       
        charatatime("Output 2\n");  
    }   

    printf(“Count = %d”,count);
    exit(0); 
}  

static void charatatime(char * str)
{
    char * ptr;     
    int c;  
    for(ptr = str; c = *ptr++; )
    {
        count++;        
        putc(c, stdout); 
    }
}
```

I'm not that good yet with C and race conditions, so my answer is mostly a guess. But if I saw this on an exam, I would say "The program splits a process into a parent and child process; the child process prints 'Output1' and the parent prints 'Output2', one character at a time. Then the total number of letters is printed at the end of the program; however, this variable 'count' may be inaccurate, as a race condition exists between the child and parent. Either can access and update count at any time, which can lead to inaccuracies."

From my understanding, race conditions arise when two or more threads or processes try to access or set the same shared variable, and the only incident of that I can see in this program is 'count'. Am I anywhere near correct, and if not, what could be added to this program to create a race condition (hypothetically, of course; I know that's not what we would want to do)?

Comment: +1 for making a reasonable attempt at this before posting on SO

Comment: `count` is not shared here, each process has its own copy.

Comment: Not really a race condition, but the putc would interlace between both threads.

Comment: Right, right...because only multiple threads that would split from this process would share it, right? Does that mean there is no race condition?

Comment: `fork` creates processes, not threads. Not much is shared to the new process. Most of it is copied to create the new process.

Comment: Aren't these two *processes* the moment you skip past that `fork()`. At that time isn't the only *race* between who gets to dump a `putc()` in the IO queue to the console before the other? There is no threading issue that I see. And regarding Neil's comment, it *may* interlace between *processes*, but I would be surprised if the child weren't outright finished before the parent even resumed (or vice-versa).

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, that's right

Comment: Although if the IO was line-buffered in stdio it wouldn't really matter much. There would be no interlacing of characters but who knows which would appear first.

Comment: The root cause is charatatime() is not atomic, replace the for loop with printf will work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as `count` is concerned, there is no race: each of the two processes has its own separate `count`.

As to the order in which the characters of `"Output 1"` and `"Output 2"` appear on `stdout`, there is indeed a race: the two outputs can end up arbitrarily interleaved.

Comment: Okay. So it could print out like "OOututputput 1 2" or any other arbitrary order? And this would be solved by adding a lock (somewhere)?

Comment: @CoconutJones: Yes and yes.

Comment: @CoconutJones It would depend if the standard output file descriptor was being line-buffered or not.

Comment: @CoconutJones Or it could print out "Output 1Output 2", or any of a myriad of other combinations therein. Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/madan-ram/race-Condition/blob/master/race_condition.c this would help you..

as you see that the stdout print, order of content changes because we dont't know in what order the parent and child executes the printf statement.